# View in ConstraintLayout does not fit within screen bounds

Tags: android, responsive-design, material-design, android-constraintlayout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to align 3 TableLayouts within a ConstraintLayout. I want the table with the MaterialButtons to have 1:1 dimension ratio, while the table on the top and on start still completely remains within the bounds of the screen. This is what it currently looks like:

[image: table_thats_supposed_to_be_square]

The definition of this TableLayout:

```
      <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_field_table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/play_field_row_values_table"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton style="@style/field_unpainted" />
                ...
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton style="@style/field_unpainted" />
            </TableRow> 
            ...
      </TableLayout>
```

The definition of the button's style:

```
    <style name="field_unpainted" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:strokeColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

The definition of the TableLayout on the start:

```
      <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_field_row_values_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_field_table"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/play_field_table"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_field_table">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:text="1 1"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>
            ...
      </TableLayout>
```

This is the definition of the TableLayout on the top:

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_field_column_values_table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/play_field_table"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/play_field_table"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/play_field_table">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
                ...
            </TableRow>
            ...
      </TableLayout>
```

I've tried setting the layout_constraintDimensionRatio to 1:1 on the "id/play_field_table", but then it stretches out of the screen:
[image]

Also tried setting the layout_constraintDimensionRatio to 1:1 in the button style, but then the buttons either are just not displayed or the same result as above.
I feel like the ratios should be both set for the buttons and for the table, just can't figure out correct combinations. Any advice?

Comment: need more info. I can give you a quick solution but please upload some image so that we can understand what is your end goal.

Comment: I want the MaterialButtons/TableLayout to be square. I resized the picture above:
https://imgur.com/ghooEcM

Comment: why are you using 3 tablelayout? Just tell me your design, what you want to achieve. May be a single customized recyclerview can do what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to achieve a nonogram playfield.
What layout should I use instead? I want the layouts to contain:
- 1 layout that contains the Buttons
- 1 layout that contains the number of fields that have to be painted in a row
- 1 layout that contains the number of fields that have to be painted in a column.
You can see these numbers are already nicely aligned at the start and at the top of the playfield TableLayout. All I'm having problems is setting the constraints right and getting the buttons to have a square shape.

Comment: Your material buttons are `wrap_content`, so what is the width/height of these buttons? Is there enough room on the screen to fit all the buttons, the top and side tables? If not, what can be adjusted to make everything fit? Your example has 10 columns and 10 rows, so make each button have a 1:1 ratio and the table itself should also be 1:1. If the number of columns does not always equal the number of rows, you will need to adjust the width/height of each button to get to a 1:1 ratio if you don't want any blanks space. I would start with the button table and get it right before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by setting the following values for the "@+id/play_field_table" TableLayout:

- Changed "layout_height" from "wrap_content" to "0dp" value
- Added "layout_constraintDimensionRatio" with "1:1" value
- Added "layout_weight" with "1" value to the TableRows inside the TableLayout